# SQL query stuck - comparison on different lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I m working on a very weird problem with SQL where I have to compare previous rows

```
Number    start_date                      end_date    
 -----     -------                      ------------
 1    2011-06-07 00:00:00.000         2011-07-10 00:00:00.000   
 2    2011-10-11 00:00:00.000         2011-10-11 00:00:00.000   
 3    2011-10-26 00:00:00.000         2011-10-29 00:00:00.000   
 4    2011-10-29 00:00:00.000         2011-11-15 00:00:00.000
```

Here , I have to compare the start_date and end_date on the two different line and create a view out of it.
(If the start_date is less than the previous end_date , then criteria is set to 1).

Well it should compare 2011-10-26 00:00:00.000 for 3 and 2011-10-27 00:00:00.000 on 2 for 30 days

```
Number    start_date                      end_date                 Criteria
-----     -----------                   ----------------          ------------
1   2011-06-07 00:00:00.000       2011-07-10 00:00:00.000            0
2   2011-10-11 00:00:00.000       2011-10-11 00:00:00.000            0
3   2011-10-26 00:00:00.000       2011-10-29 00:00:00.000            1
4   2011-10-30 00:00:00.000       2011-11-15 00:00:00.000            1
```

I m confused how should I proceed with this.

Any help would be helpful !!!!

Thanks !!!

Comment: Am I reading wrong, or should all the "Criteria" results be 0? Also to clarify, the "Number" is always sequential and unique, and defines the "previous row"?

Comment: There is plenty of questions on this. You would use an `INNER JOIN` that compares one less row. Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Show us what you've done, we'll help, but not do all your work.

Comment: Why StartDate `2011-10-29` turned out to be `2011-10-30`?

Comment: @Nikola The unstated rule "if the start date is the same as the previous end date it should be increased by 1" :)

Comment: Well it should compare 2011-10-26 00:00:00.000 for 3 and 2011-10-27 00:00:00.000 on 2 for 30 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to use a subquery:

```
select A.number, a.start_date, a.end_date,
    CASE WHEN start_date < dateadd(d,30,(select TOP(1) b.end_date
     from mytable B
     where B.number < A.number
     order by B.number desc)) then 1 else 0 end Criteria
from mytable A
```

Note: If the start date is the 29th day *following* the previous row's end date, `Criteria` becomes 1. By the 30th day onwards, it is 0. Tweak the `30` in the query as required.

Sample:

```
create table mytable (
    Number int primary key,
    start_date datetime,
    end_date datetime);

insert mytable
select 1, '2011-06-07', '2011-07-10' union all
select 2, '2011-10-11', '2011-10-27' union all
select 3, '2011-10-26', '2011-10-29' union all
select 4, '2011-10-29', '2011-11-15'
```

Result:

```
number  start_date  end_date    Criteria
1   2011-06-07 00:00:00.000 2011-07-10 00:00:00.000 0
2   2011-10-11 00:00:00.000 2011-10-27 00:00:00.000 0
3   2011-10-26 00:00:00.000 2011-10-29 00:00:00.000 1
4   2011-10-29 00:00:00.000 2011-11-15 00:00:00.000 0
```

Comment: Well it should compare 2011-10-26 00:00:00.000 for 3 and 2011-10-27 00:00:00.000 on 2 for 30 days

Comment: @user So instead of `If the start_date is less than the previous end_date` you mean `If the start_date is less than **30 days after** the previous end_date`? And is it 30th day, 31st day or 1 calendar month? Please update the question with more sample rows and result.

Comment: it is for 30 days. If it is 31 st days , then the criteria is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `case` like this:

```
create view vDates as
select Number,start_date,end_date, 
       case 
         when start_date<end_date 
           then 0
         else 1
       end as Criteria
from tab
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b1dd/2/1)

Answer (score 0):

A more readable way is create a function and send the correct dates:

Function:

```
create function [dbo].[CompareDates] (
    @START_DATE datetime,
    @PREVIOUS_END_DATE datetime
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    if @START_DATE < @PREVIOUS_END_DATE
        return 1
    return 0

END
```

Query (using subquery):

```
declare @dates table
(
    number int,
    start datetime,
    end_date datetime
)

insert into @dates values
(1, '2011-06-07 00:00:00.000', '2011-07-10 00:00:00.000'),
(2, '2011-10-11 00:00:00.000', '2011-10-27 00:00:00.000'),
(3, '2011-10-26 00:00:00.000', '2011-10-29 00:00:00.000'),
(4, '2011-10-29 00:00:00.000', '2011-11-15 00:00:00.000')

select *, dbo.CompareDates(dates.end_date, dates.previous_end_date)  from
(
    select number, start, end_date,
        (select TOP 1 end_date
        from @dates d2
        where d2.number < d1.number
        order by d2.number desc) as previous_end_date
    from @dates d1
) dates
```